# Add numbered section to toc without using \section

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I'd like to have a new section in line with the usual numbering, without it showing in the text.
I include multiple PDF files using the `\includepdf` command. Each of them is a subsection which I'd like to subordinate under the section. However, I can't just use `\section` because that makes a new headline in the document and I do not want this, especially because I have no other text except the files and an empty site with just the headline on it looks silly.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\includepdf[addtotoc={1,subsection,2,title1,1}]{1.pdf}

\includepdf[addtotoc={1,subsection,2,title2,2}]{2.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I want it to look like

```
1.Section
   1.1 title1
   1.2 title2
```

without having a nearly empty page because `\section` makes a new headline

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can use the `addcontentsline` command - there are lots of instances of its use on our site :)

Comment: unfortunately, \addcontentsline does not produce a number in front of the entry

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added an example. Hopefully, it's more clear what I want now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not know whether this is what is requested, but it is quite easy to add a non-existing section (or anything) to the TOC and use a section number in front of it.

User cmhughes already pointed to `\addcontentsline`

Please change the title and the corresponding section number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{section}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}{YourSectionTitle}}


\includepdf[addtotoc={1,subsection,2,title1,1}]{1.pdf}

\includepdf[addtotoc={1,subsection,2,title2,2}]{2.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Updated with some support for hyperref such that no stupid link is generated**

`hyperref` adds a 4th `{}` argument to `\contentsline` which is meant for the hyperanchor. If empty, no anchor and link is generated. If `hyperref` is not loaded, the empty 4th argument with `{}` does not harm any way, it can remain in the `.toc` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\phantomsectiontotoc}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}{}{}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\setcounter{section}{1}
\phantomsectiontotoc{YourSectionTitle}

\includepdf[addtotoc={1,subsection,2,title1,1}]{1.pdf}

\includepdf[addtotoc={1,subsection,2,title2,2}]{2.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: @Martin: Alright, please test and give feedback ;-)

Comment: How does `hyperref` react to adding contentlines manually?

Comment: @1010011010: Good question: Normal sections behave well, but a click on `YourSectionTitle` will lead to the TOC, at least that is what I guess -- I just checked. It is exactly as I wrote. I suppose, a manual `\hypertarget` can cure this problem

Comment: A special command in conjunction with `\phantomsection` should work. I will check later on

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: You do not need to use `\addtocontents` and `\contentsline` with special `hyperref` code. You simply have to use `\refstepcounter`. See my answer.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Just another way ;-)

Comment: great this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Only an addendum to [Christian's first example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187871/9057):

To have a solution with correct automatic bookmark for the `\addcontentsline` with `hyperref` you need to use `\refstepcounter` to increase the `section` counter. And you should insert `\clearpage` before adding the section entry to the table of contents, because otherwise it wouldn't refer to the page of the first included PDF page but to the page before:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage% to have the section on the correct page
%\stepcounter{section}{0}% If you need section number n instead of the next one, set section number n-1 here, because you still need:
\refstepcounter{section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}{YourSectionTitle}}


\includepdf[addtotoc={1,subsection,2,title1,1}]{example-image-a.pdf}

\includepdf[addtotoc={1,subsection,2,title2,2}]{example-image-b.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Note, this solutions works independent from using `hyperref`.

Comment: One could argue that your solution leaves a page entry in the ToC for a 'fake' section which isn't there. If this is requested, everything is fine...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer One could argue that your solution misses the page number for the `fake` section in the ToC. If this is requested, everything is fine … ;-) And one could ague that a ToC should contain only headings that are shown in the document. So one should do whatever he/she likes best.

Comment: Of course, and in fact, my old answer still has the page number, in retrospective I think a fake section should not a have page number at all, but it's up to the O.P. (which did not return for more than year ago)